# Get index of second match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

In a sheet made of names and scores, I am trying to build a sheet to display the name of the people with the best scores.
To do so:

- I sort the scores
- I get the index of the biggest value
- I offset the names list with the given index

When I want to get the second biggest value, I only have to get the index of the second biggest value on step 2.

There is a problem if two values are tied for the biggest, as MATCH() will always give me the index of the first value found.

I thought of determining the index of the biggest value, then excluding this index from the range used to determine the second biggest value, but I could not achieve it as the range lengths may be different.

I also thought of using a function or script that returns the Nth index that meets a criteria from a range, but I did not find anything to do so.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqG55.png)

Here is an example spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RrUpAjbMBze9L5OqxdyEWBnYXq98LtohdgROF8s68FI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try LARGE() fuction? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094008?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a column number and sort on that as well as on the score, then take the second element in the list:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(sort(transpose({B1:F3;column(B1:F3)}),3,false,4,true),2,1))
```

[image]

Note that the headers (players' names) are sorted along with their scores.

**EDIT**

Actually Sort in GS is a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) (in other words, according to the documentation 'range is sorted only by the specified columns, other columns are returned in the order they originally appear') so this is sufficient:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(sort(transpose(B1:F3),3,false),2,1))
```

Comment: Realised that Google sheets sort is a stable sort (leaves ties in their original order) so additional sorting by column is unnecessary - will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I needed.
Is ArrayFormula necessary?